# How to know what IP addresses to search from subnet mask?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, ip-address, subnet

Am writing simple program for searching through LAN, program have few options how to search (check single IP address, check hostname, check local machine subnet....etc).

And am stuck on "check local machine subnet" (atleast i think it could be a problem)!?

Ok, here is what might be a problem so i would like to know if there is a way to handle that in c++.

When i use `getadapteraddresses()`to get IP address and subnet mask so i could search local machine subnet, my doubts are what if `getadapteraddresses()` return subnet - 255.255.254.0 and IP - 192.160.5.10. First step is to search 192.168.5.0-255, but what next, what range should i search 192.168.6.0-255 or 192.168.4.0-255 ..?

If there is way to determine this in c++, any hint would be great.

Thank you :)

Comment: Isn't that what the router does for you?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My goal is so i can start program and choose search through local machine subnet and program gives me all IP address that are alive(with some more info MAC address, hostname ..etc)

Comment: Take the subnet mask and your IP and AND them; then, OR with this result all the combinations for the bits that in the mask are zero. These are all the addresses in the current subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute all addresses with something like

```
int count = (~netmask) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
int network = ip_address & netmask;
for (int i=1; i<count; i++) {
    int addr = network + i;
    ...
}
```

Comment: netmask is subnet? If yes, netmask should be explicitly hexadecimal when performing `(~netmask) & 0x7FFFFFFF `?  In what format should ip_address be when performing `ip_address & netmask`?

Comment: @Genato: I was assuming both netmask and ip_address to be 32-bit unsigned numbers `(b1<<24)|(b2<<16)|(b3<<8)|b4` where addresses are `<b1>.<b2>.<b3>.<b4>`.

Answer (score 0):

Dude I think you got a wrong value. 192.168.5.x is not in the range of 255.255.254.0. This subnet masks allows adresses from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.1.255. If the 5 is host part the mask has to be 255.255.248.0.

Comment: I didnt get that value it's my concern what if i encounter on example like that. Hmm how would you explain this, my subnet at home is 255.255.255.0 and my IP address is 192.168.5.20?

Comment: Perfectly valid, your subnet range is: 192.168.5.0 ->  192.168.5.255.  192.168.5.0 and 192.168.5.255 are in the subnet but are not valid address, the first is the network address and the 2nd is the broadcast address.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know that and lets not get of the road, my question was something else?